# How many numbers are there that include a given digit?

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations

Let's have 3 digit number (100-999). How many such numbers with at least one digit "2" exist?

How to make algorithm for that? Or math function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Inclusion-exclusion principle**

How many 3-digit numbers have `2` as the first digit (`2xx`)? That's right - `100`. And as the second digit (`x2x`)? `100`! And as the third (`xx2`) - the same number. Ok, now we have `300` numbers, but we forgot about numbers in the form `22x`, we count them twice. Now we need to subtract the amount of `22x`, `2x2` and `x22` numbers. Now we have `270` of them, but we forgot about number `222`, we added it three times, and subtracted three times, we need to add it again: `271`. This explanation is an example of [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

But that's not the end, we need to subtract all `0xx` numbers having `2` as a digit. Similar approach: `271 - 10 - 10 + 1 = 252`.

**Dynamic programming**

Ok, if you don't like the previous method, there is another one. Let's count the function `F(i, has2)`, where `i` - is the digit length of the number, `has2` boolean value that is equal to `true` if digits contain `2`, otherwise it equals to `false`. The recurrence relation is the following:

```
 F(1, false) = 8, F(1, true) = 1
 F(i, true) = F(i-1, true) * 10 + F(i-1, false) 
 F(i, false) = F(i-1, false) * 9
```

The answer is `F(3, true)`.

```
 F(2, true) = 10 + 8 = 18
 F(2, false) = 8 * 9 = 72
 F(3, true) = 18 * 10 + 72 = 252
```

Comment: Yes, this method I used too, but its kinda long and hard work, not mathematically right and programmatically not possible

Comment: Thats the result my pyhthon gave me as well :) Coding the solution took less effort than you put into it. Coders are lazy ;o) +1

Comment: @D3admau5 first approach can be quite simply programmed using binomial coefficients in the general case

Answer (score 1):

A quick'n'dirty with python is:

```
n  = [x for x in range(100,999) if '2' in str(x)] 

print("There are " + str(len(n)) + " numbers between 100 and 999 containing at least one '2'")
print(n)
```

Put that in https://pyfiddle.io/ to test.

Comment: Thanks, I always check and try to understand code before I use it. I am not copypaster :) Btw this looks so easy in programming language, I still can't find a way to do it this easy in math.

Comment: @D3admau5 the Python code in this answer is an example of a _brute force_ solution.  Whenever the question is, "how many...?" the brute force way is to generate them all and count them.   It can be the quickest way to answer some questions, but for others...  If you were considering the set of twenty-four digit numbers instead of the set of three digit numbers, then brute force is going to fail, and you'll need to find an analytic solution.

Comment: @D3admau5 Its easy in code because the main work (of thinking and optimizing) was spent by others constructing the parts that make the language. `range(a,b)` lazy enumerates over all the numbers, the str(x) makes a string out of each, the 'in' checks for the ''2'' inside the string and all together result in what you wanted. - and it is a brute force approach as I commented in the question. Check them all and sort them out.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the probability that we do not face the specified digit in given set `[0, 10^n]`. It’s obvious that we can derive it as `0.9^n`, then the opposite probability is

```
P = 1 - 0.9^n
```

- for `n = 1`: `P = 0.1`;
- for `n = 2`: `P = 0.19`;
- for `n = 3`: `P = 0.271`.

The following formula can help to define, how many numbers in this set contain some given digit:

```
N = P * 10^n,
```

where `n = 3` in your case.
Also in your case we should substract the number of such values in set `[0, 100]`. This gives us

```
N = N(3) - N(2) = 271 - 19 = 252.
```

No loops, no recursion, pure math.

Comment: True. Does this add anything to [DAle's accepted 2017 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47269805/3789665)?

Comment: I would say it much easier and, in complexity terms, much faster. I found out another way to solve the problem and wanted to share this solution with others.